# PNG transparent picture not showing background on Bootstrap website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't find any tutorials or questions on how to solve this. I'm using a PNG with a transparent background but the webpage isn't showing it. Any hints on what I might be doing wrong? I tried adding a transparent background to container, row and column and it didn't work.

[image: transparent]

html

```
<div class="container-fluid contato">
         <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-2 contatofilho">
                    <img class="center-block"  src="img/insta1.jpg" class="img-responsive" width = "100%">
            </div>
```

css:

```
.contato{
    border: yellow 3px solid; 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center; 
    background-color: black; 
}

.contatofilho {
    border: green 3px dotted; 
    background-color: black;
}

.contatofilho img {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: i think your picture is not transparent, it has background with white gray tiny squares that create illusion to like a transparent image

Comment: How do I test if the picture is really transparent?

Comment: @SarabjitSingh you were right, I made a more thorough research on google images and got transparent images :)

Comment: @PabloAguirredeSouza Glad, you could figure it out. Next time though, please try to link/attach every relevant material to make your question better.

Comment: Don't save it in Paint, try Paint 3D or some other (better?) software

Comment: Also You can download PNG or SVG icon on this website **https://www.flaticon.com/**